# ¿Es necesario poner dos veces htmlspecialchars()? PHP

Tags: php, html, xss

Muy buenas gente, tengo el siguiente código:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
 $n = "";
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   $n = prueba($_POST["n"]);
 }
function prueba($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
 }
   ?>

  <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
     Name: <input type="text" name="n">
     <br><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
  </form>

  <?php
    echo "<h2>Input:</h2>";
    echo $n;
  ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Como ya saben hay un posible ataque llamado XSS, para protegerse de el se usa htmlspecialchars() pero en el código de abajo se usa dos veces, si quitara el método htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) del input y solamente dejara el otro, me podrían hackear la página web, o daría lo mismo y porqué???

Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los ataques `xss` suelen darse entre otras formas, a través de formularios o a través parámetros de la `url`

Un ejemplo de cómo se dan a través de los parámetros url, es como se explica [aquí](https://diego.com.es/ataques-xss-cross-site-scripting-en-php)

Si pones en tu html algo como

```
echo "Has buscado la palabra: " . $_GET["query"];
```

Y luego escribes en tu URL. `http://example.com/search.php?query=<script>alert("hackeado")</script>`

Podrás ver que se ejecuta el script.

Lo mismo pasa con el ejemplo del `POST` dado que el usuario puede ingresar lo que sea en el formulario, podría ingresar algo como `<script>alert("hackeado")</script>` Y al momento de tú mostrarlo se mostraría el script.

De acuerdo a la [documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php). `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` solo muestra la ruta del archivo.

> http://example.com/foo/bar.php será /foo/bar.php

Por lo que no se puede manipular a través de scripts. Por lo que no sería del todo necesario a menos que uses parámetros `GET` o parámetros que uses desde la `URL`. Si podrías ser o no ser hackeado, todo depende de dónde uses el contenido que puede ser modificado por el usuario final.

[Mas sobre el tema](https://www.welivesecurity.com/la-es/2021/09/28/que-es-ataque-xss-cross-site-scripting/)

Comment: dependiendo de la configuración del servidor http (apache,nginx, etc..) `http://example.com/foo/bar.php?"><script>alert('hola')</script>` cerraría el tag del form y desplegaría un xss